# jQuery - post single files with loop from input multiple

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I need to post with jQuery files from a multiform form.
The problem is I don't know how to send each file individually with a foreach loop, so I can get upload success from each file separately.

Here's my function to send each file to PHP:

```
        var fileInput = document.getElementById ("images_upload_new_album");
        if ('files' in fileInput) {
            //console.log(fileInput.files);
            $.each(fileInput.files, function(index, val) {
                 /* iterate through array or object */
                 console.log(fileInput.files[index]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: config.site + "admin/photos/upload_test",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {file: fileInput.files[index].name},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    beforeSend: function (data) {
                        console.log("Before send.");
                        //console.log(data);
                    }, // AJAX request is about to be sent
                    complete: function (data) {
                        console.log("Complete.");
                        //console.log(data);
                    }, // AJAX request has completed
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) // AJAX request has completed successfully
                    {
                        console.log("success.");
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) // AJAX request has completed with errors
                    {
                        console.log("error.");
                    }
                });
            });
        };
```

And my PHP test function.

```
public function upload_test()
{
    $received = $_FILES;
    echo json_encode($received);
}
```

What I get from console:

```
File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModified: 1418160606000, lastModifiedDate: Tue Dec 09 2014 20:30:06 GMT-0100 (Hora padrão dos Açores), name: "100371.jpg", type: "image/jpeg"…}
Before send.
Modal it's opened
success.
[]
Complete.
```

This is my multiform:

```
<form action="http://xxxxxxx.dev/admin/photos/upload" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="file" name="images_upload_new_album[]" value="" id="images_upload_new_album" class="hidden_images_upload" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px" multiple="multiple" accept=".jpg"  />
</form>
```

Comment: And what is the problem **exactly**? Did you wrap the jQuery above in `$('#upload_form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ... });`  ?
When I ran your code, I get info in console for each uploaded file. What do you want to do with `success` callback? Why handle this in the loop? Couldn't you just handle JSON response from PHP to check each fileupload statement like: `file1 : success, file2 : fail, ...` ? What do you want to **achieve generally**? Help us to help you :-)

Comment: I don't know how to get separate response in jquery for each uploaded file.
What i'm trying to achieve is to have my files uploaded separately, so i can have something like, file 1 upload finished, then file 2 uploaded.. etc If i submit the form, all files will be submited at same time. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by recreating the POST loop:

```
    $('#new-album-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // Runs after show modal event is fired
        var fileInput = document.getElementById ("images_upload_new_album");
        if ('files' in fileInput) {
            jQuery.each($('#images_upload_new_album')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('fileinput', file);
                $.ajax({
                    url: config.site + "admin/photos/upload_test",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    beforeSend: function (data) {
                        console.log("Before send.");
                        //console.log(data);
                    }, // AJAX request is about to be sent
                    complete: function (data) {
                        console.log("Complete.");
                        //console.log(data);
                    }, // AJAX request has completed
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) // AJAX request has completed successfully
                    {
                        console.log("success.");
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) // AJAX request has completed with errors
                    {
                        console.log("error.");
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

This problem was solved based on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax